# How to determine if a class exists in the project

Tags: java

I have to make a program in which I input a class name and the program returns a true/false value if it is present in the project or not.

The idea is that the program scans all the directories of the project src. I have heard that it is possible to do this with the Reflection API, but I have no clue on how to do it?

Comment: When asking homework type questions, show your best good faith attempt to solve it and tell what problems you are having. This will give us a better understanding of what you're trying to do, what you might be doing wrong, and what you need help with. Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help), the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask), sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: The name of a java source code file must be the same as the public class it contains. Hence you only need to search for a file with the class name and a `.java` extension. Hence no need for reflection. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Abra what about non public classes? Albeit it is not recommended to do, you can have multiple top level classes sitting in the same Java source file.

Comment: @Abra there might be multiple class declaration in a single `.java` file.

Comment: @GhostCat I was trying to get the OP to clarify his question. Was I too subtle?

Comment: @Abra looks like :-)

Comment: There are classes in the classpath that are accessible too.  These would not necessarily be in the src folders at all.  And basic classes like java.lang.String are  not in the src folders either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the class loader.  Any class that is reachable from the same class loader as "FindClass" can be found.  Remember to use the class's package name as part of the name:  "package.class".

```
public class FindClass {

  public boolean findClass(String className) {
    try {
        FindClass.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(className);
        return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

An alternative to using the above classloader is to use the class loader that loaded the application.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(className);
```